# Get recent posts from last four recent categories

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm new with wordpress and php, but i need to get the recent posts from recent categories.   I tried to take the categories of recent posts and add them to an array with four element of categories. Then bring out the last two posts of these categories. For this I need a little help. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you would want to get the categories using something like [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-categories-by-most-recently-updated-1).

Then you would want to take those categories and make a new WP_Query that is filtered for [those categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) (probably using `category__in`.

So something like

```
$cat_array = array();
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5
  );
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $cat_args=array('orderby' => 'none');
    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'category', $cat_args);
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
      $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
    }
  endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();

$args = array(
    'category__in' => $cats,
);
$query_cats = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query_cats->have_posts() ) {
    while ($query_cats->have_posts()) : $query_cats->the_post();
        //display your posts
    endwhile;
}
```

Note that the code above has not been tested, but should be fairly close.